# How to include a static mapping file as part of a nodeJS module?

Tags: node.js, npm

Assume that I have a nodeJS module whose `index.js` is as below

```
module.exports = function() {
    var map = {},
        CSV_FILE = "./input.csv",
        _loadCSV = function() {
            var fs = require('fs'),
                parse = require('csv-parse'),
                rawCSVData = fs.readFileSync(CSV_FILE).toString(),
                i,
                item;
            parse(rawCSVData, {columns: true}, function(err, data) {
                for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    item = data[i];
                    map[item.key] = item.value;
                }
            });
        },
        _init = function() {
            _loadCSV();
        };

    // Init
    _init();

    // Public
    return {
        /**
         * getValue
         */
        getValue: function(key) {
            return map[key];
        }
    };
};
```

Now, everything works fine if I test locally. However, when I install this module in another project I get below error.

```
fs.js:549   return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
             ^
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'input.csv' at Error (native)
```

Is it possible to include a static mapping file as part of a nodeJS module that is used in module initialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is this line `CSV_FILE = "./input.csv"`. It works locally because the script you're executing (`index.js`) is in the same directory as the `input.csv`-file. However, when you install it as a dependency, the `input.csv`-file is actually somewhere in `./node_modules/your-module/input.csv`, hence your *new* `index.js` can't see any `./input.csv`-file since it's not located in the same directory as the calling script.

There are two ways to solve this, the first one being the smartest in my opinion.

1. Do not distribute the `input.csv`-file. This is a very bad approach to building modules, and you should rather change your code so that your module accepts a path to a `.csv`-file that it loads. However your module may need static data, but in those cases it's smarter to just convert it to a JavaScript Object and include it directly.
2. Simply change one line of code,
   from `CSV_FILE = "./input.csv"`
   to `CSV_FILE = __dirname + "/input.csv"`

See [documentation for `__dirname`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname)

Comment: Fundamentally I agree that distributing the CSV with the package is a bad approach, so I'll try to convert it to a JavaScript object and include it directly. Thank you for the both the pointers! Appreacite it.